# C#: is there an equivalent class of TimerTask from Java in C#?

Tags: c#

I am looking if there is an equivalent class of TimerTask from Java in C#?

The TimerTask of Java is referenced to here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Thanks in advance.

The purpose of this is that I need to implement some code following in C#:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

private static Timer timer = new Timer();

private TimerTask timeoutTask;

if (timeoutTime>0)
{
  timeoutTask = new TimerTask() { 
    public void run() 
    {
      // callActivity();
    }
  };
}

timer.schedule( timeoutTask, timeoutTime);
```

If you could provide me an equivalent code in C#, that would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29712348/925202

Comment: You can use https://timerutil.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). There are four common timer types in .NET:

- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for timers in WinForms apps
- `System.Windows.DispatcherTimer` for timers in WPF/Silverlight apps
- [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
- `System.Timers.Timer`

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) compares all but DispatcherTimer.

Comment: I have added my code that I would need to convert to C#. could you please reply one more time? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoesyXHN: The classes are reasonably simple to use, and fairly well documented - could you try it yourself and post *specific* questions with bits you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule tasks then there is a very good opensource library [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

[System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

System.Timer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx

Depending on what you're doing, a BackgroundWorker may also be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx