# C#: is there an equivalent class of TimerTask from Java in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: is there an equivalent class of TimerTask from Java in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713818/c-is-there-an-equivalent-class-of-timertask-from-java-in-c)

Hi,

I am looking if there is an equivalent class of TimerTask from Java in C#?

The TimerTask of Java is referenced to here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

The purpose of this is that I need to implement some code following in C#:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

private static Timer timer = new Timer();

private TimerTask timeoutTask;

if (timeoutTime>0)
{
  timeoutTask = new TimerTask() { 
    public void run() 
    {
      // callActivity();
    }
  };
}

timer.schedule( timeoutTask, timeoutTime);
```

If you could provide me an equivalent code in C#, that would be great!

Comment: I am sorry to create another one. As my first question is not completed and I thought nobody is going to answer it further. Therefore, I created another one. No it is not a homework assignment. I am working on a project of adding more features for the current program written in Java. therefore, for some particular parts from java, I have to rewrite in C#. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the timer to wait some interval, you might want want one of .Net's Timers:

- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
- [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

(the first one is easier to use with Forms).

Comment: I posted pretty much the same thing as an answer to the OP's near-identical question yesterday. I don't think the OP is looking for guidance - they're looking for someone to do all the work for them, it seems. :(

Comment: Thanks for catching the duplicate. Should've caught that.

Comment: It's only because I happened to answer it yesterday :)