# Equivalent of Timer in C# in Java?

Tags: c#, java, timer

In C#, the timer will trigger an event at a specific interval when enabled. How do I achieve this in Java?

I want to make a method to be run at a specific interval. I know how to do this in C#, but not Java.

Code in C#:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the method
}
```

I tried `Timer` and `TimerTask`, but I am not sure whether the method will run when other methods are running.

Comment: You can use https://timerutil.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the right classes. The [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) are the right ones, and they will run in the background if you use them something like this:

```
TimerTask task = new RunMeTask();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 1000, 60000);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {    
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // your code
    }
};
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [codeplex library](https://timerutil.codeplex.com/) to implement this.

**Schedule a task to run every second with initial delay of 5 seconds**

```
new Timer().Schedule(DoSomething, 5000, 1000);
```

**Schedule a task to run everyday at 3 AM**

```
new Timer().Schedule(DoSomething, Timer.GetFutureTime(3), Timer.MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). It has `delay` in constructor:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS_INT, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: You should not use this. These come out the swing package, which is really not what you want.

Comment: Why not? I don't see any issue here.

Comment: It adds an unnecessary dependency on Swing.

Comment: Swing is the part of the default JRE. So, this dependency is not leading to any efforts, isn't it?